# VS 2013 Not Obeying Nuget Configuration in AppData

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a file in %appdata%/nuget/nuget.config with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\BTR\packages" />
  </config>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Then in a project, I have the following in a packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

If I delete the Newtonsoft dll from /bin and rebuild, I would expect it to download the package to c:\btr\packages, but it downloads it to \packages in same folder as solution.

Any ideas why this isn't obeying the setting?  I don't (to my knowledge) have any other Nuget.config files anywhere that would override this setting.

Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE* : See Matt Ward's comment below.

Comment: What happens if you manually restore the packages at the command line with `nuget restore foo.sln`? What about if you build using MSBuild from the VS command line?

Comment: Did you close and re-open the solution after changing the NuGet.Config file?

Comment: CL restore didn't do anything.  I don't know how to use MSBuild (nor do I really want to learn ;) ).  @MattWard - It did appear to be the problem (or at least related).  After a few changes, restarts, etc., it started obeying.  Other wierd nuget behavior I'm battling where nuget 'installs' will not fix previously incorrect assembly references, but will create new SO question later if it persists.

Comment: @MattWard I would go further and restart Visual Studio. Especially since this is the global NuGet.config; I think it only loads at IDE startup.

Comment: @Heliac - In NuGet user specific NuGet.config information stored in memory is reset when the solution is closed so there is no need to restart Visual Studio. This is the case in the question posted. The only NuGet.config files which are not reset are machine wide NuGet.Config files stored in c:\ProgramData and changes to these would require Visual Studio to be restarted. Changes to NuGet.Config in %appdata%/nuget does not require Visual Studio to be restarted, just the solution to be closed and re-opened.